# Is it possible to send a Selector to the frontmost application's first responder (i.e. the focused element) with permission?

Tags: swift, selector, axuielement

#### Update

Not sure the accessibility framework is the way to go here.  Seems it only lets you interact with other apps, but not do things like programmatically send selectors to them.

For more context, macOS has user-defined key-bindings (`~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`) where you can specify a key binding and a selector that will be sent to whichever app/control has focus when you press it. This happens at the OS level.

Wondering if there's a way to programmatically do something similar, sending selectors from my own app (provided it's requested the appropriate permissions to do so, of course.)  I thought that was the Privacy->Accessibility settings, but it looks like I may be going down a wrong path.

### Original question.

Just playing around with the accessibility framework, trying to send a selector to the first responder (i.e. the focused element) in the foreground app, regardless if that app is mine or something else.

To test this, I'm trying to send `moveToBeginningOfLine:` to whichever text field has the focus.  If it receives it, the cursor should move to the beginning of the current line.

Now to send it to the first responder in my own application is easy.  You use `NSApplication.sendAction` with a target of 'nil' like in my `sendToFirstResponder` extension seen below. But this doesn't work with other applications, only your own.

To speak to other applications, you have to use `AXUIAutomation` (and make sure your app has been granted permissions to use it, which mine has), and even though it appears I am successfully getting a focused `AXUIElement` in the code below, it never seems to receive the selector as I would expect, and the call reports as failing.

Here's my code I'm playing with...

**Selector Extensions:**

```swift
extension Selector {

    @discardableResult
    func sendToFirstResponder(from sender: Any? = nil) -> Bool {
        return NSApplication.shared.sendAction(self, to: nil, from: sender)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func sendToFrontmostApp() -> Bool {

        let systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()
        var untypedFocusedElement : AnyObject?

        let getFocusedElementResult = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute as CFString, &untypedFocusedElement)
        guard getFocusedElementResult == .success else {
            print("Couldn't get the focused element. \(getFocusedElementResult)")
            return false
        }

        let focusedElement = untypedFocusedElement as! AXUIElement
        let action = description as CFString

        let performActionResult = AXUIElementPerformAction(focusedElement, action)
        guard performActionResult == .success else {
            print("Couldn't perform the action '\(action)'. \(performActionResult)")
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

**Test Code:**

```swift
// If you send this to a TextField, the cursor moves to the beginning of the line
let selectorName = "moveToBeginningOfLine:"
let selector = Selector(selectorName)

// This works if the current app is focused and a TextField is the first responder
let result1 = selector.sendToFirstResponder()
print("Result 1:", result1)

// This always fails on the 'perform action' step, even if there's a focused TextField in the frontmost app
let result2 = selector.sendToFrontmostApp()
print("Result 2:", result2)
```

Is this possible?